# How do i send a message including a reaction with discord.py

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, discord.py

How do I send a Message that is including a reaction?
I want a user to be able to trigger the command using **!Test** and that the Bot replies with test and a Red Cross as reaction.

My Code:

````
@client.command()
async def Test(ctx, message = "test"):

  Message = await ctx.send(apme, "️‍")
  await client.add_reaction(Message, emoji="redCross:423541694600970243")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, I had to do a little bit of digging and I found u have to use [unicode](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) for emoji

you can use the same concept for making commands.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "poll" in message.content:
        mm = await message.channel.send("react to this")
        await mm.add_reaction('\U0001f44d')
 
    await client.process_commands(message) 


@client.command()
async def  poll(ctx,*,polltext):
    mm = await ctx.send(f'{polltext}')
    await mm.add_reaction('\U0001f44d')
    await mm.add_reaction('\U0001f44e')
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to take shortcuts a lot of the time, so I personally would write it like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands

Client = discord.Client() # Initialise Client 
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "?") # Initialise client bot

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ready")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "!test" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("test :x:")
client.run("input token")
```

call me lazy, but it works XD.